# Execute stored procedure only during pageload and form submit

Tags: php, mysql

This is the scenario:
I want to execute a MySQL stored procedure from a PHP page only on two events:

1. Execute/CALL the sp the first time the page is loaded
2. It will execute again after every time a form is submitted via POST

But it will NOT execute if the page is Refreshed (by clicking the refresh button in the browser).

The page is available to logged-in users only.

Can someone please suggest possible solutions to such a scenario?

Comment: 1. Store this in a session or cookie 2. You could cache the page and only refresh if the timevalue in your db is greater than the time you cached the file (e.g. filemtime) - update the timevalue in the db every time a form is submitted. If noting is submitted you always have your static page on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by saving some SESSION variables and then checking those variables when the page is refreshed.